# using Where in views Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, filter, laravel-5.1, view

I'm relative new in laravel, in my first app I have a method in the controller that pass a list of links to the view, but in the view I only need some of those links so in the view I have this:

```
$links->where('menu_id', 2)
```

This works in my developer environment but don't work in production server.

Someone knows why? or knows another way to filter the results in the view?

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: that's strange. Did you check your `.env` file and set database username and password correctly? also, check log file to find any glitch.

Comment: Have you tried {{ dump($links) }} to check if it's a Collection?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
@foreach($links as link)
    @if($link['menu_id'] == 2)
           // your logic
    @endif 
@endforeach
```